# Can I query data within an hour range for all days?

Tags: druid

Using Apache Druid, is it possible to query all data within 11AM and 5PM for example, using the default timestamp field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of.  You'd have to specify multiple intervals, one for each day:

```
"intervals": [
  "2019-05-17T11:00:00Z/2019-05-17T17:00:00Z",
  "2019-05-18T11:00:00Z/2019-05-18T17:00:00Z",
  "2019-05-19T11:00:00Z/2019-05-19T17:00:00Z"
]
```